# Lifting an Iso into the first argument of a Bifunctor

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, isomorphism, bifunctor

`Control.Lens.Iso` contains many wonderful functions for lifting `Iso`s into various type arguments of useful abstractions.  For example:

- `mapping` for arbitrary `Functor`s
- `contramapping` for `Contravariant` functors
- `dimapping`, `lmapping` and `rmapping` for `Profunctor`s
- `bimapping` for `Bifunctor`s

I am looking for the function to lift an `Iso` into the `first` argument of a `Bifunctor`, but it doesn't seem to be there.  I am currently defining it thusly:

```
firsting
  :: Bifunctor f
  => AnIso s t a b
  -> Iso (f s x) (f t y) (f a x) (f b y)
firsting p = bimapping p (iso id id)
```

Does this function already exist somewhere, or is `bimapping p (iso id id)` as good as it gets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

Thanks to your question, the next version of `Control.Lens.Iso` [will include](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/commit/0da78a979f4da1a969b319eda995003ac4b322ef) `firsting` and `seconding`.

---

`iso id id` looks a bit ugly. Let's try to take that apart.

```
type Iso s t a b =
  forall f p . (Functor f, Profunctor p) =>
                               p a (f b) -> p s (f t)

--plain :: Iso s t s t
--plain = iso id id

plain :: (Functor f, Profunctor p) => p s (f t) -> p s (f t)
plain = id
```

So you can cut your implementation down to

```
firsting p = bimapping p id
```

This is probably the most concise form. If you want to really get to the bare bones, of it, read on.

Inlining the definition of `bimapping`

```
bimapping :: (Bifunctor f, Bifunctor g) => AnIso s t a b -> AnIso s' t' a' b' -> Iso (f s s') (g t t') (f a a') (g b b')
bimapping f g = withIso f $ \ sa bt -> withIso g $ \s'a' b't' ->
  iso (bimap sa s'a') (bimap bt b't')
```

and simplifying using `first`, you get

```
firsting p = withIso p $ \ sa bt ->
             iso (first sa) (first bt)
```

This is a particularly clear expression, I think. It uses `withIso` to break `p` into the two functions that make up the isomorphism, uses `first` to lift each of them to apply to the first argument of the bifunctor, and then packages them back up with `iso`. If the relevant bifunctor has an optimized `first` that does something better than can be done with `bimap`, then this will also be faster than the implementation using `bimapping`.

Inlining `iso` gives

```
firsting p = withIso p $ \ sa bt ->
             dimap (first sa) (fmap (first bt))
```

Finally, inlining `withIso` (digging into `Control.Lens.Internal.Iso`, which we probably shouldn't do),

```
firsting p =
  case p (Exchange id Identity) of
    Exchange sa bt ->
      dimap (first sa) (fmap (first (runIdentity #. bt)))
```

---

By the way, the type signature for `plain`, without the redundant context, is

```
plain :: p s (f t) -> p s (f t)
```

This is exactly the same as

```
plain :: Equality s t s t
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown; `bimapping p id` is nice.  Sometimes with all the fancy type synonyms I overlook that optics are just functions :)

Comment: @frasertweedale, you're welcome. I've written `seconding`,  generalized the types of that and `firsting` to allow two different bifunctors (as in `bimapping`), and suggested my preferred implementations [on GitHib](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/pull/619).